# Get Sum of Int Data from Firebase Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore

Hi everyone I need to make a **sum** of the values ​​I get when I read the data from **Firestore**.

In my **DB Firestore** I have a list of votes and I need the sum of all of them. I have tried various ways but I have not been able to achieve my goal ... At this point I wanted to ask you how to get a sum of the values ​​recovered from the query in **Firestore**

**This is how I save my values ​​in Firestore**

```
 var data = [

        "Votazione" : "\(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "addExam.Vote.ref"))"

        ] as [String : Any]

         // Save in Firestore

 let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
     if let user = user {
         FirestoreManager.userRootExam(forUID: user.uid).addDocument(data: data) { (error) in

            if error != nil {
                print("Saved")
             }
         }
     }
     else { print("Non esiste un current User : Documento non Salvato")}
```

This is the way I retrieve my data from the database

```
 FirestoreManager.userRootExam(forUID: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).getDocuments { (snapShot, error) in
        if error == nil {

            for doc in snapShot!.documents {

                let votes = doc.data()["Votazione"]
                // Print of votes
                  //Optional(25)
                  //Optional(22)
                  //Optional(22)

                // Print Sum of Votes ( 25 + 22 + 22 )
                print(totalVote)
            }
        }
```

As you can see I need the `totalVote` value *(total sum of all recovered values)*

Comment: Assuming `votes` is an array of optional `Int` values: `let totalVote = votes.compactMap { $0 }.reduce(0,+)`

Comment: @koen 
Hi and thanks for your suggestion ... These are values ​​saved through the use of UserDefaults.standard.set (value, forKey: "addExam.Vote.ref") with integer value .. I have implemented your suggestion but it gives me back this error **Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'compactMap'**

Comment: That means that `votes` is not an array. Please update your question (not in the comments) explaining what `votes` is. Maybe using some sample data.

Comment: @koen 
When I retrieve the data with doc.data () ["Votazione"] it returns it to me from firebase as a Dictionary

Comment: We cannot help you if you don't update your question explaining what the type of `votes` is. What do you get if you add `print(votes)`?

Comment: @koen Il print di "Voti" ottengo quello che ho scritto nella mia domanda  

// Print of votes
                  //Optional(25)
                  //Optional(22)
                  //Optional(22

Comment: @koen 
I updated my question showing how I save the values ​​.. I hope this is what you asked me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you are saving only one integer value in each `data` object, but you typecast it as `Any`. So you need to cast it back to `Int` when you retrieve the data and want to get the sum.

To get the sum of the votes, I think you need to do something like:

```
var totalVotes = 0

for doc in snapShot!.documents {
   if let vote = doc.data()["Votazione"] as? Int {
      totalVotes += vote
   }
}

print(totalVote)
```

Let me know if this works.